# NGINX rewrite IP.Board URLs for Xenforo

Tags: nginx, php, rewrite

I am having a hell of a time getting rewrites working under NGINX to rewrite old URL's to point at a new file.

XenForo's forums offer up this config:

```
location /ipb/ {
    if ($uri ~* /(topic|forum|user)/) {
        rewrite ^ /ipb/ips2xf.php? last;
    }

    if ($args ~* (^|&)show(topic|forum|user)=) {
        rewrite ^ /ipb/ips2xf.php? last;
    }

    if ($args ~* ^/(topic|forum|user)/) {
        rewrite ^ /ipb/ips2xf.php? last;
    }
}
```

however my site does not operate under a directory, it operates in a root of a subdomain. I was told simply changing the location argument to "location /" and removing the /ipb/ from the rewrite instructions would work, but that is not the case. I have tried this about a hundred different ways now and have not gotten anywhere after the past two weeks of trying.

Right now, all that's happening is whatever URL I throw at it, say "http://forums.tvnewstalk.net/index.php?/forum/10-general-tv/" will just get passed directly to index.php. I haven't actually been able to prove it's being evaluated by the rewrite rules at all, since no matter what it appears to pass the URL to index.php as-is. I've poured through error logs and redirect logs and can't find what's wrong.

Thoughts?? Suggestions?? I'm starting to lose my sanity over this.

The entire config file for this subdomain:

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name beta.tvnewstalk.net

#change your log path as according to your server
access_log  /home/tvnewstalk/logs/access.b.log;
error_log  /home/tvnewstalk/logs/error.b.log;
rewrite_log on;

root    /home/tvnewstalk/www/xf;
index   index.php index.html;

gzip on;
client_max_body_size 30M;

# Main location
location / {
    if ($uri ~* /(topic|forum|user)/) {
        rewrite ^ ips2xf.php? last;
    }

    if ($args ~* (^|&)show(topic|forum|user)=) {
        rewrite ^ ips2xf.php? last;
    }

    if ($args ~* ^/(topic|forum|user)/) {
        rewrite ^ ips2xf.php? last;
    }
}       

location /internal_data/ {
    internal;
}

location /library/ {
    internal;
}

## Static files location
location ~* ^.+.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires 30d;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

Comment: Set the logging verbosity to `debug` (put `debug` at the end of the `error_log` line, after the filename), make a request, read the logs to see what it's doing wrong.

Comment: It actually won't log anything when I do that. If I create another request (like take the question mark after index.php out of the URL) it logs that as a 404, and even shows that the rewrites are reading correctly.